# Why can a linearly polarized light be also called plane polarized light?

Tags: terminology, polarization

Today I learned that plane polarization is *also* referred to **linear** polarization. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_polarization) from where I found this does not explain why this is so.

I understand plane polarization completely till high school level. I know the Law of Malus, Brewster's law, and know how to do simple numericals involving successively placed polarizors at inclined differently to each other.

However, I am unable to understand why can a linearly polarized light be also called plane polarized light? To me, it does not make any sense, because planes are 2D physical entities, while lines (from "linear") are 1D.  How can both the terms be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the electric field is constant, and it forms a plane with the direction of propagation of light; whereas an elliptical polarization require a whole volume, considering propagation in time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Is it possible to explain without " elliptical polarization" I haven't been taught that yet. Thank you!

Comment: Circular polarization, for example, is a particualr case. In general, any wave where the electric field is switching direction in each oscillation is not a linear polarization.  If $\vec{E}$ is "rotating" around, it does not form a plane with the direction of propagation. The direction of E should remain the same. Check out the Internet to see it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As you were taught, plane polarization and linear polarization are different names for the same thing.

Plane polarization refers to the case where the electric field is always in one plane.  The electric field vector can point in any direction perpendicular to the direction in which the light is traveling.  It is possible for light to contain a vertically polarized component and a horizontally polarized component.  If the two components are exactly in step with each other, their E vectors add to produce a vector at an angle that is somewhere between vertical and horizontal, and the light is still plane polarized.  The "tip" of the E vector is still always in one plane, but the plane is tipped away from vertical or horizontal.  In fact, the "tip" of the E vector traces out a sinusoid curve in that plane.  Looking straight along the direction of the light's travel, the "tip" of the E vector would appear to move back and forth on a line -- so it's also called linear polarization.

If the two components are equal in magnitude but 1/2 wave out of step with each other, the light is circularly polarized, which means that the "tip" of the E vector moves in a helix. Looking along the direction the light is traveling, the E-vector would seem to move around a circle. The projection of the E vector's motion onto a vertical plane is just a sinusoid curve; and the projection of the E vector's motion onto a horizontal plane is also a sinusoid curve; but the two curves are a half-wave out of step with each other.

If the two components are a half wave out of step and do not have equal magnitude, the polarization is elliptical: the E vector traces out a squashed helix, and looking along the direction the light travels, the tip of the E vector would seem to trace out an ellipse.  If one component has much smaller magnitude than the other, the squashed helix approaches the plane polarization case.

http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/beyersdorf/Archive/Phys158F06/11-9%20polarization%20of%20light.pdf contains a pretty good introduction to polarization, and the Wikipedia article [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_polarization][2] isn't bad.